Optimizing Parallel Execution of Sequential and Dependent I/O and CPU-bound Tasks in Python
I have a simple processing pipeline that consists of just a couple of steps:
def run():
    SIZE = 100
    values = get <SIZE> entries from DB 
    for v in values:
        # 1. Update Status for file in DB
        # 2. Then download file from BLOB storage
        # 3. Then generate thumbnail for file (cpu-bound)
        # 4. Then send thumbnail to cloud for processing 
        # 5. Then send processing result to cloud to further process
        # 6. Then write processing result to DB

It's mostly IO bound tasks except for the task of generating a thumbnail. What techniques can I use being able to process as many files as possible without horizontally scaling?
Right now I am creating multiple threads and run the tasks in parallel but it's quite limited using a ThreadPoolExecutor with 10 workers.

Are you sending the data to your cloud using async functions or are you simply waiting for it to resolve?

right now I am not using any async functions. So this could be a small improvement. But I would have to mix async with multithreading. I'd be interested in how pseudo-code of this could look like if you could share.

You have to generate the thumbnail in another process (or remote server) or it will block the threads in current process.
